# How do I assure that all files from a shared HFS+ drives are always writable by all users?

Tags: sharing, permission

I have a shared drive on a Mac and I keep having problems accessing different directories.

For example, while logged on the server as root I create a new folder `aaa` on this drive.

Now, I discover that a normal user cannot write to this directory.

Is there a way for me to change the default permissions/ACLs so I prevent this from happening in the future.

I am looking for a one-time solution, not running `chmod` or `chown` each time.

Details:

- it seems that `root` is not member of `staff` group because when I do `ls -l` I see group `_unknown` listed for files created by root.
- By default the files do get only xr write for the group (`drwxr-xr-x`), how can I change so the group will have the same rights as the user, by default?
- Can this be changes per mounted volume or directory, or changing this would affect the entire system? Risks?

Answer (score 1):

Get Info on said drive and checking Ignore Ownership might help you.